# Shortcode coming out at the top of content rather than in place where I require it

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm aware it is probably a return problem. So I divided the content up, one in a function called `thelist` and the other being an actual function returning it. The code follows the question.

The actual shortcode works, except the contents appear at the top before the rest of the content. I thought the `now_include_post` return would fix it, however it does not. Can anybody help?

```
function thelist() {
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>  
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"  <?php post_class('thumb'); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="thumb-link">
            <?php
    if (!post_password_required())  {
                    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    }
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/locked.png"  />
        <?php } ?>
            </a>
            <h2>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
        </div>
<?php /* end post */ ?>
<?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    }
    ?>
    <?php

function now_include_post($atts) {
$thepostid = intval($atts[id]);
query_posts("p=$thepostid");
$output .= thelist();
return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want to return all the text rather than outputting it then and there when you are escaping PHP.

At the start of your thelist() function start an output buffer with

```
ob_start();
```

Then at the end close this buffer and return its contents with

```
return ob_get_clean();
```

That will return the content rather than echo it straight away, which is what you want to do in the case of a WP shortcode

[PHP information on Output Buffering Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Comment: That really is exceptional. Thank you so much for your help and that link!

Comment: It's 2014 and after 2 year your reply save me :) Thanks!